# Graphing using R

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

I want to draw `multiplot` graphing using [r](/questions/tagged/r) and I want the value of  in X-axis for each site and the different lines in the graph are M, T, L, and G but at the beginning of the code, I got an error,

> $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

```
Graphdata <- as.data.frame(multiplot)
par(mfrow=c(4,3))
plot(Graphdata$Sites$A, Graphdata$f, ylim=c(0,16), xlab="Number of years", 
     ylab="Relative density", lwd=2)
lines(Graphdata$Sites$M, type="l", col="blue", lwd=2)
lines(Graphdata$Sites$T, type="l", col="green", lwd=2)
lines(Graphdata$Sites$L, type="l", col="grey", lwd=2)
lines(Graphdata$Sites$G, type="l", col="orange", lwd=2)
```

and some of my data is

Answer (score 1):

You need to subset as follows:

```
SiteA<-Graphdata[Graphdata$Sites=="A",]

plot(SiteA$f,SiteA$M)

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

That said, I'm a fan of the `tidyverse` and think it would give you an easier solution. You'll need to `reshape2` your data although `gather` can do just fine. **EDIT** You'll also need to decide what to do with the missing values.

```
library(tidyverse)
Graphdata %>% 
  gather("MySite","MyValue",3:ncol(.)) %>% 
  filter(Sites=="A") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(`f`,MyValue,col=MySite))+geom_point()+geom_line()
```

This yields:
[image]

Comment: I want series of similar graphs on the same page like, I want 4 rows with 3 columns par(mfrow=c(4,3)) of such graph from different site on the same page.

Comment: I don't really understand. Hopefully someone else helps answer the question. The sites are L,M,T and G,right? Or are they A and B?

Comment: The sites are A, B,....N and L, M, T and G are abbreviations for Models. You have given me pretty good hint and the graphs seems what you have drawn and it is a bit refinment@NelsonGOn. The above data is not full data, it is just part of the whole data.

Comment: You could plot the graphs as in this answer and align them using `grid.arrange` from `gridExtra` or `cowplot`

Answer (score 0):

You could tack on to your ggplot call using the `facet_wrap` function and use the 'MySite' variable as your faceting variable